# Why is bibguru not detecting an ISBN reference?

Tags: citations

The WHO have a [report](https://www.who.int/teams/noncommunicable-diseases/hypertension-report) entitled

> Global report on hypertension The race against a silent killer

ISBN 978-92-4-008106-2

When I put the ISBN in BibGuru it cannot find the report.  Which is strange as it's not like the WHO is a fringe organisation making up ISBN references.

It's also sadly ironic because I'm sure the intention is to highlight the silent killer but I can't cite the report via BibGuru.  Any ideas why the ISBN cannot be found on BibGuru?

Comment: Are you sure BibGuru's database covers WHO reports in the first place? The documentation in the help section seems to be rather lacking so it's hard to tell. And what do you mean by "I can't cite it"? Surely you can add it manually?

Comment: Changed question to read *I can't cite the report via BibGuru* I like to use these services to be sure I don't get anything wrong. I thought the point of an ISBN is to have a central registry that service can reference? BibGuru advertise ISBN to citation as a service

Comment: For what it's worth, the "+More" button seems to allow adding references manually via BibGuru. Given that there are many ISBN registration agencies covering different countries (remember, the system was introduced in 1970) it seems at least possible that such websites wouldn't cover everything. Anyway, I hadn't heard of the site until your post, so I have no definitive answer.